# Dispatcher has no subscribers for MessageGateway channel when manually starting outbound gateway in test

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am writing an integration test for my TCP outbound gateway using Kotlin DSL.

When I start my application normally, I can see the output in the logs:

```
Adding {ip:tcp-outbound-gateway:lunaOutGateway} as a subscriber to the 'lunaInChannel' channel
Channel 'application.lunaInChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
```

In my test, I configure `@SpringIntegrationTest` to not autostart the `lunaOutGateway`.  I do this so that I can start a server, get the port of the server and then set the port on the client gateway before starting it.

When I do this, I do not see any traces in my log of the input channel, no subscriptions, no mention.  I get the following error message:

```
o.s.i.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage...
```

My flow does subscribe to the channel as you will see in the code at the end of this question.  I am wondering if it may be a bug in how the integration flow dsl is wired up for kotlin or in general for this edge case.

This is my non-test configuration:

```
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(LunaClientProperties::class)
class LunaClientConfiguration(
        private val props: LunaClientProperties,
        private val applicationEventPublisher: ApplicationEventPublisher
) {

    @MessagingGateway(
            name = "lunaGateway",
            defaultRequestChannel = "lunaInChannel"
    )
    interface LunaGateway {
        fun send(message: String) : String
    }

    @Bean
    fun lunaSerializer() = LunaSerializer()

    @Bean
    fun lunaDeserializer() = LunaDeserializer()

    @Bean
    fun lunaNetClient(): TcpClientConnectionFactorySpec = Tcp.netClient(props.host, props.port)

    @Bean
    fun cachingClientConnectionFactory(
            lunaSerializer: Serializer<String>,
            lunaDeserializer: Deserializer<String>,
            lunaNetClient: TcpClientConnectionFactorySpec
    ) :  CachingClientConnectionFactory {

        val tcpConnectionFactory: AbstractClientConnectionFactory = lunaNetClient
                .soTimeout(props.socketTimeout)
                .serializer(lunaSerializer)
                .deserializer(lunaDeserializer)
                .get();
        tcpConnectionFactory.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);

        return CachingClientConnectionFactory(
                tcpConnectionFactory,
                props.poolSize);
    }

    @Bean
    fun lunaClientFlow(cachingClientConnectionFactory: CachingClientConnectionFactory) =
            integrationFlow("lunaInChannel") {
                handle(
                        Tcp.outboundGateway(cachingClientConnectionFactory)
                                .remoteTimeout(props.remoteTimeout)
                ) { id("lunaOutGateway") }
            }
}
```

Note the source of the flow specified as `lunaInChannel`.

My test code:

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@DirtiesContext
@SpringIntegrationTest(noAutoStartup = ["*lunaOutGateway*"])
@SpringBootTest(classes = [LunaClientConfiguration::class, LunaIntegrationTests.Config::class], webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
class LunaIntegrationTests(
        @Autowired private val lunaGateway: LunaClientConfiguration.LunaGateway,
        @Autowired private val lunaOutGateway: TcpOutboundGateway,
        @Autowired private val lunaNetClient: AbstractClientConnectionFactory,
        @Autowired private val lunaServer: AbstractServerConnectionFactory
) {

    @MockkBean(relaxed = true)
    private lateinit var props: LunaClientProperties

    @BeforeAll
    fun setup() {
        if (!lunaOutGateway.isRunning) {
            println ("GW NOT RUNNING")
            TestingUtilities.waitListening(lunaServer, 10000L)
            lunaNetClient.port = lunaServer.port
            lunaOutGateway.start()
        } else {
            println ("GW IS RUNNING")
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun blah() {
        val r = lunaGateway.send("Hello Gary")
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableIntegration
    class Config(@Autowired private val applicationEventPublisher: ApplicationEventPublisher) {

        @Bean
        fun serverCF(): TcpNetServerConnectionFactory {
            val tcpNetServerConnectionFactory = TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(0)
            tcpNetServerConnectionFactory.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher)
            return tcpNetServerConnectionFactory
        }

        @Bean
        fun lunaServerFlow(serverCF: AbstractServerConnectionFactory) =
                integrationFlow(Tcp.inboundGateway(serverCF).id("lunaServer")) {
                    handle {
                        println("${it.payload}")
                    }
                }
    }

}
```

It is work in progress so the server is not properly handling requests.  The properties class is currently mocked and should not impact this problem.

The autowired constructor arguments are for the message gateway, the TCP outbound gateway in the flow, the bean that creates the tcp client and the test server.

I am getting this on Spring Boot 2.3.2.RELEASE train.

Can you please help me to get this to work?

Kind regards,
Alwyn

Comment: The only workaround I have found so far is to autowire the channel into the test and subscribe the gateway to the channel manually after starting the gateway.

Comment: Try to start it not in the `@BeforeAll`. More over I don't see a reason to stop it and start manualy. The gateway is passive component in your case and it does its stuff only when you call it with that `send()`.

Comment: @ArtemBilan So if I understand you correctly I can still set the client port to the server one in the `@BeforeAll` and it will use that port to connect only once I call send.  Correct?

Comment: I did a quick test and it throws an error that you cannot change the port while it is running.  So I called stop(), changed the port, called start() and it seems to be working without the need to subscribe to the channel.  Thanks!